# How do I change the x value of the player character on key press using 2 separate methods

Tags: java, keyboard, char, move, keypress

The first part of the code, with the key inputs, vk_down etc. I'm not allowed to change at all, the second part, my code I am. I need to know how to perform the players movement, where x and y r their positions in the performaction() method while using the char's attached to the setkey function in the first part of code. I don't know how to properly link them. There are currently no errors but when I play, the character doesn't move

Also it has all the keyevent imports etc. already

thanks in advance

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
    // Below, the setKey method is used to tell the Player object which key is
    // currently pressed.

    // The Player object must keep track of the pressed key and use it for
    // determining the direction
    // to move.

    // Important: The setKey method in Player must not move the Player.
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        this.player.setKey('L', true);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        this.player.setKey('R', true);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        this.player.setKey('U', true);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        this.player.setKey('D', true);
    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
        this.continueGame = false;
    return;
}
```

---

```
char c;    
public void performAction() {
    if (c == 'L') {
        this.x += -10000;
    }
}

public void setKey(char c, boolean b) {

}
```

Comment: Is this some sort of school assignment?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then:

```java
public void performAction(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case "L": this.x += -10000; break;
        case "R": this.x += 10000;  break;
        case "U": this.y += 10000;  break;
        case "D": this.y += -10000; break;
    }
}

public void setKey(char c, boolean b) {
    // do some stuff
    // ...
    performAction(c);
}
```

UPD: 
Using private field of current character:

```java
class SomeClass {

    // ...
    // Keep the value
    private char c; // (5)

    public void performAction() {
        // Read the value
        switch (this.c) {
            case "L": this.x += -10000; break;
            case "R": this.x += 10000;  break;
            case "U": this.y += 10000;  break;
            case "D": this.y += -10000; break;
        }
    }

    public void setKey(char c, boolean b) {
        // ...

        // Having used 'this.' you can invoke variable of the class (aka 'field')
        // which declared at 5 line.
        //
        // Assign a new value to the field.
        this.c = c; 
        performAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I am able to pass through c using the brackets, since in the original "untouchable" file it doesn't have any parameters, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Then use private field of current character.